# Store database into an array using java swing

Tags: arrays, database, swing, ms-access

I have two windows. A Login window (which is called main; I'm still just testing) and a MainWindow. I'm reading the login data (username, password) from an MS Access database. The database has four tables, Customer, Accounts, Mortgage, CreditCard. Everything is working fine so far, but I'm trying to pass the First Name and Last name of the user to a JLabel in the Main Window when they have successfully logged on. How do I do this? Do I need a customerindex when the user has logged on? Do I need to store it in an array before I can pass it between frames? If so, how do I do that? I'm still learning so an example would be great.

I'm assuming my array will look something like this?

```
Account accounts[] = new Account[2];
Customer people[] = new Customer[2];
CreditCard credit[] = new CreditCard[2];
Mortgage mortgage[] = new Mortgage[2];
int index = 0;
```

This is my login class

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Login extends JFrame
{
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
JLabel l = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Password");
JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
JButton b = new JButton("Login");

public Login()
{
    connect();
    frame();

}

public void connect()
{
    try
    {

        //Connect to the database
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://G:/JSProject/prjTIMS_JS/Bank.mdb");
        st = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully ...");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

public void frame()
{
    f.setSize(600,100);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(l);
    p.add(t);
    p.add(l1);
    p.add(t1);
    p.add(b);

    f.add(p);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
            String username = t.getText().trim();
            String password = t1.getText().trim();

            String sql = "select username, password from tblCustomer where username = '" +username+"'and password = '"+password+"'" ;
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            int count = 0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                count ++;
            }

            if(count == 1)
            {
                setVisible(false);
                new MainWindow();
            }
            else if(count > 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate User, Access Denied!");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Not Found!");
            }




            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Catch Error");         
            }
        }
    });
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Login();

}}
```

MainWindow

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

MainWindow() {
    //Create a new frame container
    setTitle("Jo's Dealership: Main Menu");


    //Give the frame an initial size and center the window
    setSize(390, 270);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Terminate the program when the user closes the application
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("pc.png");
    JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(image);
    lblImage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(48, 48));

    JLabel lblOptionMsg = new JLabel(" choose an option below.");
    lblOptionMsg.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblOptionMsg.setForeground(new Color(37, 75, 124));

     //Make two buttons
    JButton okButton = new JButton ("OK"); 
    okButton.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12));
    okButton.setOpaque(false);
    okButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 22));
    okButton.setForeground(new Color(37, 75, 124));

    JButton cancelButton = new JButton ("Logout");  
    cancelButton.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12));
    cancelButton.setOpaque(false);
    cancelButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 22));
    cancelButton.setForeground(new Color(37, 75, 124));

     JRadioButton buyButton = new JRadioButton("Buy Car", true);
     buyButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
     buyButton.setActionCommand("Buy");
     buyButton.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 11));
     buyButton.setOpaque(true);
     buyButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 22));
     buyButton.setForeground(new Color(37, 75, 124));

     JRadioButton calcButton = new JRadioButton("Calculate Commission", true);
     calcButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
     calcButton.setActionCommand("Calculate");
     calcButton.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 11));
     calcButton.setOpaque(true);
     calcButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 22));
     calcButton.setForeground(new Color(37, 75, 124));

     ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
     bG.add(buyButton);
     bG.add(calcButton);
     buyButton.setSize(100,200);
     calcButton.setSize(100,200);

    //Create text based label
    JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel("[CustomerNameHere] is currently logged on.");
    lblMessage.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblMessage.setForeground(new Color(37, 75, 124));

    //Add the panel to the content page
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(239, 239, 239));

    //Display the frame
    setVisible(true);

    //Set the layout
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    //Add the label to the content pane
    panel.add(lblImage);
    panel.add(lblMessage);
    panel.add(lblOptionMsg);
    panel.add(okButton);
    panel.add(cancelButton);
    panel.add(buyButton);
    panel.add(calcButton);

    //Adjust constraints for the components
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblImage, 150,  SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblImage, 50, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblMessage, 75, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);  //right
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblMessage, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);  //top
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, okButton, 90, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, okButton, 185, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cancelButton, 195,  SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cancelButton, 185, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, buyButton, 95,  SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, buyButton, 105, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, calcButton, 95,  SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, calcButton, 135, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblOptionMsg, 105,  SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblOptionMsg, 25, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override 
        public void run() {
            //new MainWindow(0).setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way if you want to pass the First and Last Name of the logged on user to the MainWindow.

First, modify your query to get Last and First name when you verify if user exists in your database :

```
String sql = "select FName, LName from tblCustomer where username = '" +username+"'and password = '"+password+"'" ;
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

int count = 0;
String lastName ='';
String firstName = '';
while(rs.next())
{
  count ++;
  //get last name and first name when connected
  lastName = rs.getString("LName");
  firstName = rs.getString("FName");
}
```

And then :

```
if(count == 1)
 {
   setVisible(false);
   new MainWindow( firstName+" "+lastName);//<--pass it here to the mainWindow
 }
```

Finaly, in your MainWindow :

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    private String whosLoggedOn;
    MainWindow(String whosLoggedOn) {
         this.whosLoggedOn = whosLoggedOn;

         //------ other stuff--------

         //Create text based label
         JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel(this.whosLoggedOnis+ " is currently logged on.");
        //------ other stuff--------

  }
  }
```

**EDIT 1:**
If you want to pass other information from other tables, for example `tblCustomer` and `tblAccount`, you could modify the constructor of MainWindow like this :

```
  public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    MainWindow(ResultSet tblCustomer, ResultSet tblAccount ) {


         //use them as you want here
         //for example to get last and first name :
          String lastName = tblCustomer.getString("LName");
          String firstName = tblCustomer.getString("FName");

         //Create text based label
         JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel(lastName +" "+ firstName" is currently logged on.");
        //------ other stuff--------

  }
  }
```

Now in your login `JFrame` you'll just have to query the tables you want and pass the `ResultSet` to the `mainWindow` when connected.

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop (!!!) That worked so well. I have other tables with added information, so I can just use this process instead, and pass my data that way?

Comment: I followed your steps to load another table but I'm hitting a snag. I have another table. Example: String sqlAccount = "SELECT custID, checkingAcctNum, savingsAcctNum, soarAcctNum FROM tblAccount.... I can't pass the firstName and lastName in the MainWindow and use the whosLoggedOn again. I'm not sure how I can pass both tables to the MainWindow. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: I tried querying the windows to pass the ResultSet to the other windows but I'm getting the "Catch error" message. Could it be that I'm not doing the query correctly? When I went back to the initial way you showed me, everything worked. :-/